# Filter is not a function?

Tags: javascript

Im attempting to return an array of my list items if they contain the text "Flexbox" in them.

Im getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: items.filter is not a function`

```
    <ul>
        <li data-time="5:10">Flexbox 1</li>
        <li data-time="5:10">Something else</li>
        <li data-time="5:40">Flexbox 2</li>
        <li data-time="5:10">Something also else</li>
        <li data-time="5:40">More Flexbox for you</li>
    </ul>


'use strict';

var items = document.querySelectorAll('li');

var itemsFlex = items.filter(function(item) {
    return item.includes('Flexbox')
});

console.log(itemsFlex);
```

Comment: That's a very good question, the reason is hard to see at the first view, but if you analize the return type you will notice that NodeList is the type returned by querySelectorAll method

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) not an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). You can convert it to an Array if you'd like to use Array methods.

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var itemsArray = Array.from(items);
```

Comment: Readers should be aware that not all browsers (looking at you IE11 in standards mode, although it's not just you) support `Array.from`.

Comment: Short and sweet! Thanks, it helped a lot! And will be by sure

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that querySelectorAll is not returning an array.

You can transform the NodeList into an array via:

```
var itemsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("li"));
```

Source: https://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array

Comment: That's the pure true! It's hard sometimes to realize that with this kind of method. Clever from you.

Answer (score 2):

The `querySelectorAll` does not return an `array`, that is the reason why `filter` is not defined (which is a function of `array`). In this case, you should call `filter` function from `Array.prototype` and use `textContent.indexOf(string)` to check if the element has the text content you want (`Flexbox`). For sample:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var filter   = Array.prototype.filter;

var itemsFlex = filter.call(items, function(item) {
    return item.textContent.indexOf('Flexbox') >= 0;
});

console.log(itemsFlex);
```

See the sample here:
    https://jsbin.com/hibixipoyo/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList`. `NodeLists` are array-like but don't feature many of the methods provided by the `Array`, like forEach, map, filter, etc. 
 If you want to use this functions, you must transform the NodeList into an array:

```
var nodesArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('li'));
```

Comment: *"like forEach"* - NodeLists *do* have a `.forEach()` method now, though it's not supported in older browsers. (I don't think any version of IE supports it.)